# JavaScript - cannot set property of undefined - Apigee

Tags: javascript

I am keep getting the below error

```
{
    "fault": {
        "faultstring": "Execution of Testing1 failed with error: Javascript runtime error: \"TypeError: Cannot set property \"case\" of undefined to \"120\". (Testing1.js:3)\"",
        "detail": {
            "errorcode": "steps.javascript.ScriptExecutionFailed"
        }
    }
}
```

My code is as below

```
var Backend_Response = JSON.parse(context.getVariable('response.content'));
Backend_Response.test.case = 120;
context.setVariable('response.content',JSON.stringify(Backend_Response));
```

I am trying to add a nested JSON in to my code with case as the nested object. Expected output is

```
{
    "Primary": "Status",
    "test": {
        "case": 120
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: This means that `Backend_Response` doesn't have a `test` property. What does `console.log(Backend_Response)` show? Add the output to the question (not a comment).

Comment: If you're **adding** `test.case` then you'd want `Backend_Response.test = { case: 120 }`. Tangential: it may be better to pick a single variable naming convention, `camelCase` or `snake_case`.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Barmer for immediate response. I have tried below and it worked now.

```
var Backend_Response = JSON.parse(context.getVariable('response.content'));
Backend_Response.test = {};
Backend_Response.test.case = 120;
context.setVariable('response.content',JSON.stringify(Backend_Response));
```